# I can't get my value from my input to be stored in my app.component.ts

Tags: html, angular

So i'm trying to store an input from my form into a property but when I submit my console.log returns undefined in the console itself.

These are the variations I tried but didn't work

```
<form>
<input #in1 type="text" id="username" placeholder="username" value="5">
<input type="password"  id="password" placeholder="password">
<input type="submit" (click)="onSubmit(in1.value)" id="submit" placeholder="submit">
</form>









<form #myForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" id="Log-email" ngControl="Email" ([ngModel])="SUsername.Email"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1" >Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="Log-pass" ngControl="pass" [(ngModel)]="SPassword.pass">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <input type="button" (click)="test()" value="test">
      </form>
```

And heres the typescript part of it

```
SUsername:string; 
SPassword:string;

onSubmit(){
console.log(this.SUsername,this.SPassword);
```

}

Comment: Dont you have to initialize the SUsername and SPassword before storing in their properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do with this:

```
private model : any = { Email: "", pass : "" };
```

> EDIT:

- HTML Code with `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"` and `[(ngModel)]` (which was
  already `([ngModel])`)
- Removed `<input type="button" (click)="test()" value="test">`

HTML Code:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" id="Log-email" ngControl="Email" [(ngModel)]="model.Email" name="Email"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1" >Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="Log-pass" name="Email" ngControl="pass" [(ngModel)]="model.pass">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Make Sure:

you have written `[(ngModel)]` not `([ngModel])`

A [`working demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-demo-s8gru6) with your code example:)

Comment: Do I use the submit button or the test button that directly has a click action to the method that sends the data, its confusing a little bit

Comment: use only single button

Comment: So I used the submit button but it still returns empty on my server
screenshot: http://prntscr.com/nrebyp

Comment: @TypeFInTheChat Check the modified answer! Now added demo with your code!

Answer (score 0):

`SUsername` and `SPassword` should be initialized as objects

```
SUsername = {Email: ''}
SPassword= {pass: ''}
```

Comment: So I tried this
SUsernname = {Email: ''}
  SPassword = {pass: ''}
  
  test(){
   
    this.service.PostLogin(this.SUsernname.Email,this.SPassword.pass);
  }
 but the console log on my server still sends me undefined when I press the button

Answer (score -1):

you need to have a name attribute for the Html tag element that is same as ([ngModel])="SUsername.Email"